# Sumifs summing when conditions evaluate false?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, formulas

I have a sheet with five columns: ID1, ID2, date, quantity, and the cumulative sum that match both ID1 and ID2. The last is a `sumifs` shown below

[image]

And even though the ID1  (4) and ID2 (2) first occur in row 4 it is summing to 1. What is going on?

The Google sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NRqbsJreu1uJ3ViBBg7NSVbEkNj9_ANkl96Xo6tevyY/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: The same data and formula give the correct answer in Excel. I think it's a rounding error problem (or bug, even) but it's difficult to find exactly what's happening.

Comment: try enclosing the formula in `ARRAYFORMULA()`

Comment: @TomSharpe, I think it is likely a rounding error as well. Because I continued playing with it and I put in a `-1E-10` and that fixed the issue